# How can I group a list of objects by continuity?

Tags: python

Given a very large (gigabytes) list of arbitrary objects (I've seen a similar solution to this for ints), can I either group it easily into sublists by equivalence? Either in-place or by generator which consumes the original list.

```
l0 = [A,B, A,B,B, A,B,B,B,B, A, A, A,B] #spaces for clarity
```

Desired result:

```
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['A'], ['A'], ['A', 'B']]
```

I wrote a looping version like so:

```
#find boundaries
b0 = []
prev = A
group = A
for idx, elem in enumerate(l0):
    if elem == group:
        b0.append(idx)
    prev = elem
b0.append(len(l0)-1)

for idx, b in enumerate(b0):
    try:
        c = b0[idx+1]
    except:
        break
    if c == len(l0)-1:
        l1.append(l0[b:])
    else:
        l1.append(l0[b:c])
```

Can this be done as a generator `gen0(l)` that will work like:

```
for g in gen(l0):
    print g
....
['A', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
....
```

etc?

EDIT: using python 2.6 or 2.7

EDIT: preferred solution, mostly based on the accepted answer:

```
def gen_group(f, items):
    out = [items[0]]
    while items:
        for elem in items[1:]:
            if f(elem, out[0]):
                break
            else:
                out.append(elem)

        for _i in out:
            items.pop(0)
        yield out
        if items:
            out = [items[0]]

g = gen_group(lambda x, y: x == y, l0)

for out in g:
    print out
```

Comment: So you want to split a list into sublists so that each sublist starts with "A" as first element and contains only this single "A" element?

Comment: no, I want each sublist to have only the first A and however many B's come after it.

Comment: Is it a safe assumption that the list starts with an "A"?

Comment: @jambox Yes, that's what I meant. So each time an "A" occurs in the list, we end the previous and start a new sublist. The delimiting element is always "A", the elements in between are arbitrary. Right now?

Comment: Yes it is, to both questions.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple generator to perform your task:

```
def gen_group(L):
    DELIMETER = "A"
    out = [DELIMETER]
    while L:
        for ind, elem in enumerate(L[1:]):
            if elem == DELIMETER :
                break
            else:
                out.append(elem)

        for i in range(ind + 1):
            L.pop(0)

        yield out
        out = [DELIMETER ]
```

The idea is to cut down the list and yield the sublists until there is nothing left.  This assumes the list starts with "A" (`DELIMETER` variable).

Sample output:

```
for out in gen_group(l0):
    print out
```

Produces

```
['A', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
['A']
['A']
['A', 'B']
['A']
```

## Comparitive Timings:

`timeit.timeit(s, number=100000)` is used to test each of the current answers, where `s` is the multiline string of the code (listed below):

```
                       Trial 1  Trial 2  Trial 3  Trial 4 |  Avg
This answer (s1):      0.08247  0.07968  0.08635  0.07133   0.07995
Dilara Ismailova (s2): 0.77282  0.72337  0.73829  0.70574   0.73506
John Coleman (s3):     0.08119  0.09625  0.08405  0.08419   0.08642
```

This answer is the fastest, but it is very close.  I suspect the difference is the additional argument and anonymous function in John Coleman's answer.

```
s1="""l0 = ["A","B", "A","B","B", "A","B","B","B","B", "A", "A", "A","B"]

def gen_group(L):
    out = ["A"]
    while L:
        for ind, elem in enumerate(L[1:]):
            if elem == "A":
                break
            else:
                out.append(elem)

        for i in range(ind + 1):
            L.pop(0)

        yield out
        out = ["A"]

out =gen_group(l0)"""

s2 = """A, B = 'A', 'B'
x = [A,B, A,B,B, A,B,B,B,B, A, A, A,B]
map(lambda arr: [i for i in arr[0]], map(lambda e: ['A'+e], ''.join(x).split('A')[1:]))"""

s3 = """def subListGenerator(f,items):
    i = 0
    n = len(items)
    while i < n:
        sublist = [items[i]]
        i += 1
        while i < n and not f(items[i]):
            sublist.append(items[i])
            i += 1
        yield sublist

items = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
g = subListGenerator(lambda x: x == 'A',items)"""
```

Comment: It's good but I wanted a general solution - A and B are just placeholders so it could be C, D or (actually) arbitrary objects where I compare some attribute so it would work with obj0.att1 == obj1.att1. I think this is basically it though, give me a minute to think about it...

Comment: As to timings, I'd call that a draw, really.

Comment: @jambox, decided to do a few more trials, its pretty much a draw

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
def subListGenerator(f,items):
    i = 0
    n = len(items)
    while i < n:
        sublist = [items[i]]
        i += 1
        while i < n and not f(items[i]):
            sublist.append(items[i])
            i += 1
        yield sublist
```

Used like:

```
>>> items = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
>>> g = subListGenerator(lambda x: x == 'A',items)
>>> for x in g: print(x)

['A', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
['A']
['A']
['A', 'B']
```

Comment: Passing the function seems a bit superfluous, is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: @wnnmaw The original question referred to breaking "arbitrary objects" into sublists according to some unspecified notion of equivalence. I suspected that it has little to do with string equivalence but that there is some Boolean function for determining if a new sublist should start. Obviously it would be easy enough to modify the code so that the condition is hard-wired into the generator.

Comment: Yes this is it, I wanted it to work on arbitrary objects, so this is better in that sense. OTOH @winmaw your one is consuming the input list, which I asked for! Well, only got one tick to give... awkward.

Comment: @jambox, added some timing results to my answer, this one is the fastest!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that A is your breakpoint.

```
>>> A, B = 'A', 'B'
>>> x = [A,B, A,B,B, A,B,B,B,B, A, A, A,B]
>>> map(lambda arr: [i for i in arr[0]], map(lambda e: ['A'+e], ''.join(x).split('A')[1:]))
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['A'], ['A'], ['A', 'B']]
```

Comment: agreed, nice one-liner but i can't ''.join(x) a multi-gigabyte list... :)

Comment: @IronFist well i wouldn't use it for anything serious... it is clever though.

Answer (score 1):

The following works in this case. You could change the `l[0] != 'A'` condition to be whatever. I would probably pass it as an argument, so that you can reuse it somewhere else.

```py
def gen(l_arg, boundary):
    l = l_arg.copy()    # Optional if you want to save memory
    while l:
        sub_list = [l.pop(0)]
        while l and l[0] != boundary:   # Here boundary = 'A'
            sub_list.append(l.pop(0))
        yield sub_list
```

It assumes that there is an `'A'` at the beginning of your list. And it copies the list, which isn't great when the list is in the range of Gb. you could remove the copy to save memory if you don't care about keeping the original list.

Comment: Cool but wouldn't the
    l = l_arg.copy()
use a lot of memory given the large input?

Comment: See the last sentence. Basically, if you don't need the list after, you can just remove the first line of the function.

Comment: OK my fault, I hadn't noticed you said that. Another thing is that 'A' is hardcoded, whereas I said arbitrary objects. So John's solution gets points for that because with his I can pass in an equivalence func.